# Cant remove whitespace from number (PHP/JS)

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have a Magento store where I need to remove a whitespace from a number so I can use it later on for dividing the price and stuff.

The code is as simple as this:

```
<script>
var newprice = <?php echo $newprice;?>
document.write(newprice);
</script>
```

If the price is less than 1000 (three numbers), it outputs correctly. If the price is four numbers, it wont output at all. Though I can see from the source code that the variable is stored correctly, example:

```
var newprice = 1 089
```

What I need is to remove this whitespace, but it doesnt seem to be that easy. I have tried:

```
var newprice = "<?php echo $newprice;?>" // with quotes
document.write(parseInt(newprice));
```

This outputs only "1". I have also tried the following code, but it outputs 1 089 (with whitespace):

```
document.write(newprice.replace(" ", ""));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you use trim() in js

Comment: `Number('1000 1'.replace(' ', ''));`

Comment: uzaif: I tried trim, and I dont think it does anything because the whitespace is between the numbers.
Rayon: Your code works as intended with your custom number. When I replace '1000 1' with variable newprice I get output `NAN`, like this (from source code):
    var newprice= "1 099";
    document.write(Number(newprice.replace(' ', '')));</script>
NaN`

Comment: @BTB, Can you `console.log(newprice);` ?

Comment: try var newprice = <?php echo intval($newprice); ?>

Comment: @KarthikN, How will that make any difference mate ?

Comment: `var newprice = <?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $newprice);?>;`

Comment: @BTB, `var newprice= "1 099"; document.write(Number(newprice.replace(' ', '')));` did work for me!

Comment: @Rayon Dabre may be the value in $newprice can be a string...

Comment: @KarthikN, Let it be `string`, we do have `replace` method of `string`

Comment: Yeah that works for me aswell, when I set newprice to be 1 099 like that. But the $newprice php variable is getting the price from Magento (with: `$_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false)`) - so I guess there is something very special about that whitespace from Magento price... :/

Comment: @Rayon Dabre Data sanitization before rendering values in html. By the way the newprice is initialized as a number in javascript but trying string operation?

Comment: @KarthikN, If it is wrapped in `"`, it will not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd. I smell a rat. I think the 'space' you see may not be a space (ASCII character code 32) but some other character that maybe isn't in the character set. Is everything in your site set to UTF-8?

Normally we would expect to see a comma or a period here: `"1,089"` or `"1.089"`. The thousands separator is set in the PHP locale. See the output of [localeconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)

I recommend you study where `$newprice` is set within your Magento code. I think it is a string. A string for displaying price in a way that makes sense to humans.

For the little computer that needs a number instead of a string you might be better with `$_product->getFinalPrice();` which returns a float or some such function that gets the price as a number instead of a human readable string.

Failing that, based on my suspicion that your 'space' is not a char(32), a brute force `preg_replace(anything that isn't a digit, period or comma)` may be more effective than string replacements (notwithstanding multi-byte character codes):

```
var newprice = <?php echo(preg_replace("#[^0-9\.\,].#","",(string)$newprice).";"); ?>
```

Comment: Great answer. You are totally right, probably it wasn't a "space". The last method with `preg_replace` works perfect. Now I can use it to divide with different prices. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var newprice = <?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $newprice);?>
document.write(newprice);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your value from the php can be a string

```
var newprice = <?php echo intval($newprice); ?>
```